# Need RPC call example written in C#

Tags: c#, c++, wmi, rpc

I am dealing with WMI connection errors and timeouts and will try to check the RPC stack first. I found the following C code snippet, but do not understand if and how it works and where I may find further informations or even a sample.

```
RPC_STATUS status;
unsigned short *StringBinding;
RPC_BINDING_HANDLE BindingHandle;
status = RpcStringBindingCompose
  (
    NULL,                // Object UUID
    L"ncacn_ip_tcp",      // Protocol sequence to use
    L"MyServer.MyCompany.com", // Server DNS or Netbios Name
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &StringBinding
  );
// Error checking ommitted. If no error, we proceed below
status = RpcBindingFromStringBinding(StringBinding, &BindingHandle);

// free string regardless of errors from RpcBindingFromStringBinding
RpcStringFree(&StringBinding);
```

Does this code really make a connection?
Does someone has a interop declartion for C#?

Thanks so far.

br--mabra

Comment: You are scaring people away by asking for C# code and showing them ancient-looking C++.  It probably isn't actually ancient, it just looks it, but anyway try editing this as a shorter more task focused question without the C++.

Comment: Nope, it's ancient.  And has nothing to do with WMI.

Comment: Sorry, but I use it at a starting point and I need this to port to use C# instead. Now, I added a C++ tag, hope, this.helps.

Comment: Let's try and get on the sam page.  Is this the kind of thing you're trying to do?  And if so what problem are you having doing it?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Will some retagger please add a wmi tag to this topic?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  You mention WMI connection errors and timeouts, but then start asking about really low-level PRC stuff.

Comment: In many situations, a wmi connection hungs and I never found a way to prevent my task hunging also. This is often the case, when the remote machine is in some obscure state [never found, what this is;Sometimes this problem apperas after patches were applied to the machine, but the reboot was delayed. In this cases, ping works]. Specifying a timeout for the wmi connection has never had any influence on this behavior. So I am looking for a way up the stack, to test a connection and RPC came into my mind. I am not sure, that this will help, but I'll give it just a try.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the interop code for your above example:

```
class Rpc
{
    [DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RpcStringBindingCompose(
        string ObjUuid,
        string ProtSeq,
        string NetworkAddr,
        string EndPoint,
        string Options,
        out string StringBinding);

    [DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RpcBindingFromStringBinding(
        string StringBinding,
        out IntPtr Binding);

    [DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RpcBindingFree(
        ref IntPtr Binding);

    public Rpc()
    {
        string stringBinding = null;

        int retCode = RpcStringBindingCompose(
             null,                // Object UUID
             "ncacn_ip_tcp",      // Protocol sequence to use
             "MyServer.MyCompany.com", // Server DNS or Netbios Name
             null,
             null,
             out stringBinding );

        IntPtr bindingHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        retCode = RpcBindingFromStringBinding(stringBinding, out bindingHandle);

        retCode = RpcBindingFree(ref bindingHandle);
    }
}
```